# Connecting to Oracle with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am using Oracle 11g, And I am trying to get it to connect to VB.net. I have installed the Oracle data provider. I have access to the tnsnames.ora under the samples folder. However I for some reason cannot locate the listener.ora file. When trying to connect to the database I get the following error: ORA-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error. I have tried to get my database running through the services but there isn't one which shows my database.

Hope I was clear and I would any suggestions why there isn't a listener file and why this error is occurring. I have tried through tutorials, using this link http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/GettingStartedVBVersion/GettingStartedNET_VBVersion.htm and also used the wizard but still get the same error message.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to an Oracle database on your local machine?  Or to an Oracle database on a different machine (a server somewhere)?  If you are using a local database, have you verified that you can connect to the database via SQL*Plus or SQL Developer or even to the web administrative interface?

Comment: I am trying to run on my local machine. Sql developer is working fine, I dont know why but I don't have a file named listener.ora.

Comment: OK, which SQL Developer connection is working (assuming you are using one of the Auto-Generated Local Connections)?  Did you create a listener when you installed the database?  Or are you using operating system authentication in SQL Developer?  Can you connect to the database using SQL*Plus from the command line specifying an explicit service name (i.e. `sqlplus scott/tiger@dbname`)?

Comment: No I did not create the listener when the database was created, as I did not create the database. It was created for me by IT support, I am just adding data etc but want a GUI using VB. No I cannot connect using cmd either.

Comment: What version of Oracle was installed?  Do you see a "Database Control" option in the Start menu wherever your database is installed?  If you choose that, is the Database Control available?  Do you see a listener on the landing page?  Is the listener up or down?  Do you see a "Net Manager" or "Net Configuration Assistant" on the Start menu?

Comment: Oracle 11g was installed. I cannot see the database control on the start menu. I dont see a listener either.

Comment: Do you see something like "Oracle in SomeOracleHomeName" from the Start menu?  Are you *sure* that IT support installed a database on your local machine rather than simply installing a client that lets you connect to a database on a remote machine?  What does the connection that is working in SQL Developer look like?

Comment: I dont see that either. I think that the database may have been installed on the client. The connection is a private one set up from support from my uni. So I think I will need to talk to them. Thanks for the help

Comment: As suggested in the first comment you need to first establish that you can connect using SQLPLUS or SQl Developer, then you can work on your VB.Net problem. You said SQL Developer is working fine - are you saying you can connect successfully to your database through SQL Developer?

Answer (score 1):

OK.Install the ODAC with odt for your database.(32 bit).Don't edit and tns details
and add the referenece to the oracledataaccess.dll to your project.
Import these two

```
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Types
```

Then add the lines

```
Dim oradb As String = "Data Source=*your tns entry goes here*" + "User Id=uname;Password=pass;"
Dim conn As New OracleConnection(oradb)
conn.open()
```

This did the job for me.
If it works ,add the data in your tns file as it is not advised to keep the connection string in the code.